# MySQLで比較演算子を使ったSQLにインデックスを付与したいです

Tags: mysql

mysql(ver5.6.36)で以下のようなSQLに対して複合インデックスを付与しようとしております。

```
select id from test_table 
where
total_price < price1 + price2 + price3 - deposit_price
```

現時点では以下のようにwhere句で使うカラムに対して複合インデックスを付与しております。

```
ALTER TABLE test_table ADD INDEX test_index(total_price, price1, price2, price3, deposit_price);
```

explainの結果、typeは「ALL」ではなく、「index」となっておりますが、rowsが100万件を超えており、ちょっと遅いです。

このようなsqlに最適なindexの貼り方はどのようなものかご教示いただけますでしょうか。

Comment: こちらの情報によると不可能とのこと。やはり無理か　https://teratail.com/questions/11073

Comment: MySQL 5.7なら新機能のGenerated Columnsが役立つかもしれません。